# How to know which form was validated in loop-generated forms

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code I wrote to generate as many forms as there is entries in a table.
I'd like to know which Submit button (i.e. of which exact form) was clicked to then execute some SQL actions.
Thank you for your help!

```html
<?php
  require_once 'header.php';
  if (!$loggedin) die();
  $result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM audit_requests");
  $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
  echo "<div class='main'><h3>$num_rows audit requests found!</h3>";
while ($row  = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
      $requester = stripslashes($row['user']);
      $audit_request_id = stripslashes($row['audit_request_id']);
  echo <<<_END
    <form method='post' action='audit_listings.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <span class='text'><br>Audit request number</span>
    <input disabled type='text' maxlength='10' name='audit_request_id' value='$audit_request_id'>
    <span class='text'><br>Auditee name</span>
    <input disabled type='text' maxlength='16' name='user' value='$requester'>
_END;

if (getCategory($user) == 'Auditor')
 {
     echo "<input type='submit' value='Apply for this audit request'>";   
 }   
  echo <<<_END
</form></div><br>
_END;
}
if (isset($_POST['audit_request_id']))
  {
    $audit_request_id = stripslashes('audit_request_id');
    queryMysql("INSERT INTO audit_plan SELECT * FROM audit_requests WHERE audit_request_id='$audit_request_id'");
    queryMysql("UPDATE audit_plan SET applicant='$user' WHERE audit_request_id='$audit_request_id'");
    queryMysql("INSERT INTO messages VALUES('', 'TrustusChain', '$org_name', '$address', '', '$city'");    
  }
?>
```

Comment: echo everything or print_r everthing and then keep playing with it, remember sometimes doing print_r wont make your program give further output, so keep playing with them

Answer (score 0):

You could add a hidden field to the form. Like:

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"form_xxx\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate random id's to the form like

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return myfunc(this.id)" id="From_php">
```

in javascript

```
<script>

function myfunc(id){
//do anything with id of form
}
</script>
```

You can pass ajax requests to server accordingly.